# MySqli joint function with PHP to show products rating

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck in middle of creating product rating function with PHP.

Here is the scenario....

1) Table articles_ratings has following fields.
id, pd_id, rating

2) Table products has following fields
pd_id, pd_title, pd_short_desc, pd_image, pd_price, pd_desc and there are more fields...

This is my article page to show all items listed on page.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT products.pd_id, products.pd_title, AVG(articles_ratings.rating) AS rating
            FROM products
            LEFT JOIN articles_ratings
            ON products.pd_id=articles_ratings.pd_id
            GROUP BY products.pd_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<a href='article-detail.php?pd_id=".$row[0]."'><h1>$row[1]</h1></a>";
      echo "<div class='article-rating'>";
      echo "Rating ".round($row[2])."/5";
      echo "</div>";
    }

    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is articel_detail page to show info when select specific item

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$id = $_GET['pd_id'];

//echo $id;

$sql = "SELECT products.pd_id, products.pd_title,
          AVG(articles_ratings.rating) AS rating
        FROM products
        LEFT JOIN articles_ratings
        ON products.pd_id=articles_ratings.pd_id
        where products.pd_id='$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $title = $row['pd_title'];

  echo "<h3>".$title."</h3>";
  //echo "<p>".$row['pd_price']."</p>";
  echo "Average ".round($row[2])."/5<br>";
  echo "Rate this article";
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style media="screen">
    i.fa.fa-star:hover {
  color: coral;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php  foreach (range(1, 5) as $rating): ?>
      <a href="rate.php?pd_id=<?php echo $id; ?>&rating=<?php echo $rating; ?>"><?php //echo $rating; ?><i class='fa fa-star'></i></a>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php
  if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
    if ($_GET['msg']="success") {
      echo "<p>Thank you for your vote</p>";
    }
  }
   ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

This page does the work to process the rating.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

  if (isset($_GET['pd_id'], $_GET['rating'])) {
    $pd_id = (int)$_GET['pd_id'];
    $rating = (int)$_GET['rating'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO articles_ratings (pd_id, rating) VALUES ('.$pd_id.', '.$rating.')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      header('Location: article-detail.php?pd_id=' . $pd_id.'&msg=success');
    }
  }

?>
```

Issue here I am facing is that when fetch info from products table the rating auto updates to 0/5.

Kindly help with this.

Comment: `'.$pd_id.'` is incorrect concatenation. You also are open to SQL injections, you should parameterize.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I will surely consider parameterize. Where you see incorrect concatenation for '.$pd_id.', and what is the correct option there...

Comment: You need to close the encapsulation so the `.` acts as a concatenation operator. E.g.  `VALUES ('" . $pd_id . "'` or you could just use curly braces since you are in double quotes, `VALUES ('{$pd_id}'` but really it should be `VALUES (?` and bound.

Comment: Got it fixed, issue was with echo "Average ".round($row[2])."/5<br>"; which is listed in articel_detail page/table. changed it from $row[2] to $row['rating']. Works good now,